# Django foreign key not getting data

Tags: django

I have two tables defined in my models:

```
class Products(models.Model):
    productsid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_number = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=15)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True, default=datetime.date.today, null=True, blank=True)


class ProductFlag(models.Model):
    product_number = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=15)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    productid = models.ForeignKey(Products, db_column='productsid', db_index=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

I want to get the the 'title' from Products when I query ProductFlag.

In my views, I make this query:

productflags = ProductFlag.objects.filter(company__companyid=self.kwargs.get('company_id')).order_by('product_number')

I thought that I could then reference the title field in my template by looping through {% for product in productflags %} and
grabbing {{ product.productid.title }}, but I get nothing at all.  Looking at it in the Django shell, it seems that my productid is always "None" (and my database definitely had data in productsid).  I have no issue with the company foreign key.  What am I doing wrong?

My apologies, I had a typo.  I am referencing **product.productid.title** inside the loop in my template; product_number was in error.  I have double-checked my database as well, and there is data in all the fields referenced.

I don't know that this will help, but in the django shell I get this behavior:

testflags = ProductFlag.objects.filter(company__companyid=43).order_by('product_number') gets a queryset of about seven.  If I then try to access testflags[0].company.companyname, I get the actual company name.  On the other hand, if I try to access testflags[0].productid.title, I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'".

Also, if I try "testflags = ProductFlag.objects.select_related('productid').filter(company__companyid=43).order_by('product_number')" the query sees the column names in Products, but accessing them with productid, gives that AttributeError.

In pgAdmin, this query works just fine:

```
SELECT a.product_number, b.title
FROM productflag AS a
INNER JOIN products AS b 
ON a.product_number = b.product_number 
AND a.company_id = 43;
```

Thanks--

Al

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Based on the new information it seems you have a typo in the filter part of your query. Try `company_id` rather than `companyid`.

```py
.filter(company__company_id=43)
```

---

I believe the issue is in your loop. You need to access the title with

```py
{{ product.productid.title }}
```

This is assuming the query set contains some data.

Answer (score 0):

From your snippet here:

```
{% for product in productflags %}
    {{ product_number.productid.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

It looks like you're referencing the wrong variable name, because on loop, it's declared as `product` but you then go on to use `product_number`?

Try changing `product_number` to `product` or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone.  You got me to look more closely at my code.  It seems that my ProductFlag table was not being properly populated with the productid; so it was using a null value for its foreign key relationship with Products...  No valid key = no valid data.